# On server side URL parameter value after encode/decode looks 'strange'. Why?

Tags: java, server-side, urlencode, html-entities, urldecode

On client side (in Browser) URL looks like this one:

```
http://www.google.com?param1=Name1%3DValue1
```

it means, that parameter `param1` has value `Name1=Value1`

On Server Side, I see, that `param1` has value `Name1&#61;Value1`

I found info, that '`&#61;`' is `HTML` Entity (decimal) for character "`=`".

Main problem, that I do not have full access to code on server side.

Could you please provide some recommendation how I can convert `HTML` Entity to "`=`".
And What do you think, it is valid situation that on server side URL parameter has `HTML` Entity or it is bug?

Comment: What is the server? Any frameworks? Where in the call stack do you read the param? "http://www.google.com" are you running this at google? :)

Comment: something is encoding your url using XML/HTML numeric entities - you haven't told us enough for us to even hazard a guess as to why.  This isn't a normal part of any sort of standard processing chain.  I'd suggest hunting around in the source code for something like "numeric entity encoding" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is weird. I'm lost as to why URL encoded characters would be converted to encoded HTML entities. Anyway, if all you are interested in is converting it to Name=Value, take a look at this code.

```
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml("Name1&#61;Value1"));
```

Output

> Name1=Value1

Where [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29) is from the apache commons lang project.